# Else without if error that hinders code from correct output

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FantahunKeburAlmostIsoscelesRightTriangle{
public static void main (String []args){

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter the longest side: ");
            double longest = s.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter 2nd side: ");
            double second = s.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter 3rd side: ");
            double third = s.nextDouble();

            double longsq = Math.pow(longest, 2);
            double secondsq = Math.pow(second, 2);
            double thirdsq = Math.pow(third, 2);
            double secthirdsq = secondsq + thirdsq;

            double SecLongLength = second + 1 ;

            if  (secthirdsq==longsq) {
                System.out.println("This triangle is an almost-Isosceles right triangle. ");
}
            else if (secthirdsq!=longsq) {
                System.out.println("This triangle is not a right triangle. ");

            else (SecLongLength!=longest) {
                System.out.println("This triangle is a right triangle, but not almost-Isosceles.");
                            }

            }

        }
}
```

I get these errors after I try to run the code. Basically, if I input numbers like 5, 4, and 3 for longest, second, and third respectively I should get "this triangle is an almost-Isosceles right triangle" as an "Almost Isosceles Right Triangle" is a right triangle where the numbers are one integer from each other, and this function works. When I input numbers like 10, 8, and 6 I should get this output: "This triangle is a right triangle, but not almost-Isosceles." But alas, I get the errors below. I tried to make it an else if and it then gave me a ";" error which corrected and more errors came up. What can I do to get the output I want?

FantahunKeburAlmostIsoscelesRightTriangle.java:33: error: 'else' without 'if'
                else (SecLongLength!=longest) {
                ^

FantahunKeburAlmostIsoscelesRightTriangle.java:33: error: not a statement
                else (SecLongLength!=longest) {
                     ^

FantahunKeburAlmostIsoscelesRightTriangle.java:33: error: ';' expected
                else (SecLongLength!=longest) {

Comment: Check your brackets. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` after the first `else if` and before the second `else if`...

Comment: also this classname is insanely long. This should have been a RightTriangle in a package hierarachy

Comment: And `else (SecLongLength!=longest) {` should be `else if (SecLongLength!=longest) {`

Comment: The teacher from the class asked us to make our classnames LastnameFirstNameAlmostIsoscelesRightTriangle

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your code, This is wrong

```
else if (secthirdsq!=longsq) {
            System.out.println("This .......");
  else(SecLongLength!=longest) {  // this else inside if without a if
            System.out.println("This .....");
   }
 }
```

There must be a `if` to have `else`. It is obvious what is the point of having `else` without a `if`?

You can follow following order

```
if(condition1){

else if(condition2){

}else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things are wrong... 
1. the closing bracket
2. the else branch.. either else without or else-if with condition

```
else if (secthirdsq!=longsq) {
  ...
else (SecLongLength!=longest) {
 ...
}
```